# XmlNodeList xPath with namespace to filter out Nodes

Tags: c#, xpath, namespaces

I have this file that I want to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Schema Namespace="DataModel.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" ProviderManifestToken="3.5" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl">
  <EntityContainer Name="DataModelStoreContainer">
    <EntitySet Name="erpBarcode" EntityType="DataModel.Store.erpBarcode" store:Type="Tables" />
    ...
    ...
  </EntityContainer>
  <EntityType Name="erpBarcode">
    <Key>
      <PropertyRef Name="ID" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="ID" Type="uniqueidentifier" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="Barcode" Type="nvarchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="100" />
    <Property Name="ProductNo" Type="nvarchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="100" />
    <Property Name="UnitNo" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="IsActive" Type="bit" Nullable="false" />
  </EntityType>
  <EntityType Name="erpCustomer">
   ...
  </EntityType>
  <EntityType Name="erpOperation">
   ...
  </EntityType>
  ...
 </Schema>
```

I want to retrieve all EntityType nodes from the document.
First I tried the XPath expression in [XPathVisualizer](http://xpathvisualizer.codeplex.com/) and it retrieves correctly all the nodes. The problem is when I move to C#. Above is the code I am using and I cannot figure out where the error is, because the node list is always empty.

```
var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.Load(_fileName);

var xmlnsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmldoc.NameTable);

//Add the namespaces used to the XmlNamespaceManager
xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("ns1", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl");
xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("store", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator");

var xpath = @"//ns1:Schema/EntityType";
XmlNodeList nodeList = xmldoc.SelectNodes(xpath, xmlnsManager);

foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default namespaces are inherited.

```
var xmlnsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmldoc.NameTable);

xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("ssdl", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl");

var xpath = @"/ssdl:Schema/ssdl:EntityType";
// ------------------------^^^^^

XmlNodeList nodeList = xmldoc.SelectNodes(xpath, xmlnsManager);
```

note that this would work as well

```
var xpath = @"//ssdl:EntityType";
```

P.S.: There is no good reason to use `ns1` as the prefix, using the something that comes naturally makes more sense.